# I am trying to write a Python Script to Print a list of Files In Directory

Tags: python, csv

as the title would imply I am looking to create a script that will allow me to print a list of file names in a directory to a CSV file.

I have a folder on my desktop that contains approx 150 pdf's.  I'd like to be able to have the file names printed to a csv.

I am brand new to Python and may be jumping out of the frying pan and into the fire with this project.

Can anyone offer some insight to get me started?

Comment: Look into using the 'os' module for looking at file names in a directory: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html. And 'csv' for interacting with a CSV file: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html.

Comment: Do you expect any special formatting in the csv file?  i.e., would it work to just open a command window and type `dir /B > filenames.csv`?

Comment: Hello John, I do not expect any special formatting in the csv, this is really more to take inventory of the contents of a directory.

Answer (score 3):

First off you will want to start by grabbing all of the files in the directory, then simply by writing them to a file.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import csv

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("./") if isfile(join("./", f))]

with open('file_name.csv', 'w') as print_to:
    writer = csv.writer(print_to)
    writer.writerow(onlyfiles)
```

**Please Note**

`"./"` on line 5 is the directory you want to grab the files from.

Please replace `'file_name.csv'` with the name of the file you want to right too.

Comment: Hi Michael, this may the  basic of all questions but does the file that I am writing the values to have to already be created before running the script?  Or am I specifing the name of the file to create?

Comment: Hello @MetroGIS I am sorry I have taken so long to reply! I am currently on vacation. Anyhow, if you would still like to know the file you are writing to must already be created with the code above. You CAN make it however so it will make the file if it does not already exist :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
csvpath = "csvfile.csv"
dirpath = "."
f = open("csvpath, "wb")
f.write(",".join(os.listdir(dirpath)))
f.close()
```

This may be improved to present filenames in way that you need, like for getting them back, or something. For instance, this most probably won't include unicode filenames in UTF-8 form but make some mess out of the encoding, but it is easy to fix all that.

If you have very big dir, with many files, you may have to wait some time for os.listdir() to get them all. This also can be fixed by using some other methods instead of os.listdir().

To differentiate between files and subdirectories see Michael's answer.

Also, using os.path.isfile() or os.path.isdir() you can recursively get all subdirectories if you wish.

Like this:

```
def getall (path):
    files = []
    for x in os.listdir(path):
        x = os.path.join(path, x)
        if os.path.isdir(x): files += getall(x)
        else: files.append(x)
    return files
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a csv file with all *.pdf files:

```
from glob import glob
with open('/tmp/filelist.csv', 'w') as fout:
    # write the csv header -- optional
    fout.write("filename\n")
    # write each filename with a newline characer
    fout.writelines(['%s\n' % fn for fn in glob('/path/to/*.pdf')])
```

`glob()` is a nice shortcut to using listdir because it supports wildcards.

Comment: I have a couple of questions: 1. This is the location of the existing csv that will have all pdf names, correct>  2.  glob('/path/to/*.pdf')]) will contain the directory of all pdf's, correct?

Comment: `open('/tmp/filelist.csv', 'w')` creates a _new_ csv file that will have all pdf filenames in it. yes `glob('/path/to/*.pdf')` returns the list of all pdf files in the given directory.